# Java Servlet HTML Table links Shopping Cart

Tags: java, html, sql, servlets, e-commerce

i am creating a shopping cart website selling music for school using HTML Java servlet and SQL. my problem is that my get.String(recording_id) is being called twice once to display the tracklisting and the second time to take the recording_id and use it to add to the shopping cart but for some reason both will not work together they each work individually if i comment out the line but both not together

also the Add button does not sit in another column but moves.
my code

```
try{
        String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM music_recordings";

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);
        // Retrieve the results
    out.println("<center><table border=\"1\"><tr><th>Artist name</th><th>Title</th><th>Category</th><th>Price</><th>ADD?</></tr></center>");
        while(rs1.next()){
        out.println("<tr><td> "+ rs1.getString("artist_name") + "</td>");
        //out.println("<td><a href=\"musicTracks?recording_id=" +rs1.getString("recording_id")+">"+ (rs1.getString("title")) +"</a>"+"</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + rs1.getString("category") + "</td>");    
        out.println("<td> " + rs1.getFloat("price") + "</td>");



        out.println("<td>"+"<form action=\"add_to_order\" method=\"get\">" + "<input type =\"hidden\" name=\"recording_id\" value=\"" +
        rs1.getString("recording_id")+ "\">"+"<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add\" >"+"</form>");
        out.println("</td></tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table><br>");

        conn.close();

    } catch(SQLException se) {
        System.err.println(se);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead to call this method `get.String(recording_id)` twice, you can create a variable named `variableNameId` and assign it the value of `get.String(recording_id)` like this:

```
  String variableNameId   = rs1.getString("recording_id");
```

And use it where do you prefer.

Comment: my output is the same if i were just to turn "record_id" into a variable and using it the way you have said brings up a blank page in chrome

Comment: i dont understand what you mean

Comment: name="+variableNameId+" value=\""+ this is how i have it